# Count occurrence in column value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I need to count the occirance of a particular character within a column value, with multiple rows. Currently I do this in php using the `substr_count` function. This isn't ideal as I can not `ORDER BY` this value within the `SQL`. A very basic example of what I am currently doing.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN(1,3,7,12,18......)

// loop though results from PDO query above
foreach($results as $key => $val){
    print(substr_count($val['col3'], '|')); // prints number of occurances of |
}
```

Simply put, is there a way of returning the number of occurances of `|` within a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace` to replace `|` with `''`. Then take the difference of the length of original column and the modified column to get the number of `|` occurrences.

```
select length(colname)-length(replace(colname,'|','')) as no_of_|
from yourtable
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I really like the logic.